# Adding a space between the value and unity inside a equation in Word using Visual Basic

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

This is the point.

I have a document that was imported from Pages that contains a lot of equations.

The equations have things that were written with a space between the number and the unit, like:

```
100.11 m
200.32 W
```

and after importing that into Word, the equations lose the space and are now

```
100.11m
200.32W
```

**Another extra problem is that during the conversion, some numbers are expressed with a comma instead of point, for the decimal separator.**

So, my regex is this...

```
([0-9]*[\.|\,][0-9]*)([m|W])
```

Search for a number with n digits, plus a point or comma, plus another number, plus a letter m or v...

I want the spaces back, so I did the following VBA macro

```
Sub AddSpace()
    For Each eqn In ActiveDocument.OMaths
        eqn.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="([0-9]*[\.|\,][0-9]*)([m|W])", ReplaceWith:="\1" & " " & "\2", MatchCase:=True, MatchWildcards:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
End Sub
```

This script hangs word.

Answer (score 0):

Here is for the simple solution :

Edit your document in Word, use the Replace command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>),
tick "Use wildcards" and enter :

Find what : `([0-9]@).([0-9]@)m`
Replace with : `\1.\2 m`

Then click *Replace All*.

This will do all the `m`, then repeat the above for `W`.

Comment: "no results found"...

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste failed me. I corrected the find string.

Comment: Strange, but it is still not working for me. It misses a lot of formulas and when it finds something it does not replace.

Comment: Possibility of invisible characters? Put up a little file and I can have a look.